# Php ternary statement

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Hi i was recently looking over a shopping cart paginator class, trying to understand their code so i could build my own paginator when i came across the following line of code. It resembles a ternary statement but is written in a way that i have never seen before. I would google it but i wouldn't know what to google. Could someone please tell me what this is how it works and what it is called so i can do a search for it and learn more.

```
    return ($output ? '<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>' : '') 
. '<div class="' . $this->style_results . '">' . sprintf($this->text, ($total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($total - $limit)) ? $total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $total, $num_pages) . '</div>';
```

Just let me know if this is enough code to go on
Thanks
Andrew

Comment: I wonder who gets to maintain these overabused conditional operator statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called conditional operator and I would consider this to be an abuse of it. Conditional operators can be useful in reducing short if-else constructs into one statement without effecting the readability of the code.

```
if(a == b)
    c = d;
else
    c = e;
//can be written as:
c = a == b ? d : e;
```

The given code can be written as:

```
return ($output ? 
            '<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>'
         : '') . 
    '<div class="' . $this->style_results . '">' . 
    sprintf($this->text, 
        ($total) ? 
            (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 
          : 0, 
        ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($total - $limit)) ? 
            $total 
          : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), 
        $total, $num_pages) . '</div>';
```

And is equivalent to:

```
if($output)
    $str = '<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>';
else
    $str = '';

$str .= '<div class="' . $this->style_results . '">';

if($total)
    $first = (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1;
else
    $first = 0;

if((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($total - $limit))
    $second = $total;
else
    $second = ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit);

$str .= sprintf($this->text, $first, $second, $total, $num_pages);
$str .= '</div>';
```

Comment: except in their case it is just
$a = $b?c:d; which i thought was weird because i didn't realise that you could test a variable for being empty without using empty($var)

Comment: `if($output)` evaluates to `true` if `$output` is defined somewhere before and is not an empty string. Empty strings are `false`.

Comment: " When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

    * the boolean FALSE itself
    * the integer 0 (zero)
    * the float 0.0 (zero)
    * the empty string, and the string "0"
    * an array with zero elements
    * an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
    * the special type NULL (including unset variables)
    * SimpleXML objects created from empty tags "

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

As a reference for people who might come across this question while searching :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice... It is just a regular conditional operator (well, 3 of them, along with some concatenation).

If you reformat it, it gets a bit clearer:

```
$output = $output ? '<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>' : '';

$min = $total ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0;
$max = (($page - 1) * $limit) > ($total - $limit) ? $total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit);

$output .= '<div class="' . $this->style_results . '">'
    . sprintf($this->text, $min, $max, $total, $num_pages)
    . '</div>';

return $output;
```

Comment: Ok, i don't understand the first line. What does the question mark mean there i thought ternary operators went like this
$string = (condtion)?do if true:do if false;
where is the condition? or is output the condition, how can it be the condition?

Comment: I haven't seen them used in this way before, how does that work

Comment: A simple variable is an expression, too. This does return true if the variable's value "equals" true, so it should not be `0`, `false`, `array()` or an empty string...

Comment: It's like using an `if ()`: `if ($output)` is the same as `if ($output == true)` - in the same way `$output ? x : y` is the same as `$output == true ? x : y`

Answer (score 1):

```
expression ? runs if true : runs if false;
```

More here

```
 http://www.johnhok.com/2008/02/23/php-tip-tertiary-operator/
```

In your case:

```
$output ? '<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>' : ''
```

If $output variable is not empty then following is return otherwise empty '' string is returned.

```
<div class="' . $this->style_links . '">' . $output . '</div>'
```

Same is the case with other tertiary operators used in your code.

Comment: ok so if you just put a variable you are saying is this variable empty. I didn't realise you could use them this way

Comment: do you mean ($output == '' )  ? ie output is equal to nothing?

Comment: No. Just having `$output` as the condition is the equivalent of testing that it is *not* equal to nothing...